# Update Google eclipse plugin to 1.9.5 failing by "not finding artifact"

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, plugins

The precise error message is:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.standard, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Artifact not found: https://dl.google.com/eclipse/appengine/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.5.jar.
https://dl.google.com/eclipse/appengine/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.5.jar

Does anybody know this and know how to prevent it or if there is really a problem with the update source? I cannot download the related file manually, btw.

Answer (score 0):

You may have want to have a look here (https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip) for guidance to install from zip file. 
I was encountering the same problem and installed the zip file without problem.

Regards, Peter

Comment: Yes, Peter. I've tried that. And the jar, that was missed by Eclipse was also missing in that download.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar problem trying to update my Maven build to 1.9.5 and resolved the problem by using version 1.9.4 until this issue is resolved (or hope 1.9.6 works correctly).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by Google and now you can now update normally without problems.